Difficulty getting US Census ABSCBO data by sex, race and vet status
I programmatically pull American Community Survey Data constantly, but I am new to getting data from the 2022 Annual Business Survey: Characteristics of Business Owners (ABSCBO) Dataset. I would like to be able to get data from the report organized by the sex, race and/or veteran status of business owners, but I am having difficulty. For example, I am trying to find out the number of minority-owned businesses at the state level in Oregon.
I have tried to use two different approaches:
https://api.census.gov/data/2021/abscbo?get=NAME,GEO_ID,NAICS2017_LABEL,OWNER_SEX,OWNER_ETH,OWNER_RACE,OWNER_VET,OWNPDEMP&for=state:41&NAICS2017=00&OWNER_RACE=90&key=MY_KEY

and:
import requests
import pandas as pd

state = 'state:41'

cbo_variables = 'GEO_ID,NAME,NAICS2017,NAICS2017_LABEL,OWNER_SEX,OWNER_SEX_LABEL,OWNER_ETH,OWNER_ETH_LABEL,OWNER_RACE,OWNER_RACE_LABEL,OWNER_VET,OWNER_VET_LABEL,QDESC,QDESC_LABEL'

# Define the API endpoint and parameters
endpoint = 'https://api.census.gov/data/2021/abscbo'
params = {
    'get': cbo_variables,  
    'for': state, 
    'OWNER_RACE': '90',
    'key': api_key
}

# Make the API request
response = requests.get(endpoint, params=params)

# Check if the request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
    data = response.json()
    # Convert the data to a DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])
else:
    print(f"Error: {response.status_code}, {response.text}")

But I either get a 204 error or some form of data with OWNER_RACE=00 depending on how I play with the script/calls. I think I am missing something fundamental in my attempts to reverse-engineer the limited number of examples in the API documentation for that report.
Does someone with more experience with this dataset have any suggestions, please?
Thanks!
